# Should PK-PK or PK-FK link be used when it comes to 1-1 relation?

Tags: database-design, relationship

I have created 1to1 relation linking one number value (unique) to other table's PK. And Database system understands it 1to1. It workes well.

However some sources and other opinions exist which claims that both table's PK should be linked to each other when it comes to 1to1.

I have so tested the second thing. But when ID equals to each other then the child data which I wrote in the form corresponds to parent is changing. So it becoming corresponded to the wrong parent data when you run the query because of the fact that ID should be equal in this case.

What is the accurate linking approach when it comes to 1-1 relation.

Comment: see (external site): https://www.damirsystems.com/sql-x-to-y/

Answer (score 0):

One answer is shared primary key.  In this design the primary key of one table is also a foreign key that references the primary key of the other table.